# How to use Android studio Code in react Native?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Is it possible to built a module in android studio that uses the camera of the celphone and then compiled it in some war to use it in react native?
Is there some can of bridge that can allow me to use android studio code in react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write native code and run it on JS side with `NativeModules`.

[Native Modules Intro - React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro)

[Android Native Modules - React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)

You can also run or do what you want to do to your react native app from Android Studio just like any other android app.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Ionic, it's the other way around, but very helpful.

https://ionicframework.com/native

Using "Capacitor" you build the web app, and it generates an android project and loads it in android studio for further editing.